# Python: get subset of list avoiding list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I often find myself in a situation where I have a list of objects, and lists of associated parameters: param1, param2, param3 etc. I want to get the subset of objects that have parameters satisfying some conditions.
A pseudo-code would be:

```
subset = object if param1>10 and 5<param2-param3<6 and param4==1
```

I know how to do that using list comprehensions, but it gets quite ugly and can be hard to read by somebody else. Are there alternatives?
For instance, to add elements of lists two by two, the painful:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[10,10,10,10]

[item[0]+item[1] for item in zip(list1,list2)]
>>> [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

looks instantly clearer using NumPy arrays instead of list comprehensions:

```
import numpy
list1=numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
list2=numpy.array([10,10,10,10])

list1 + list2
>>> array([11, 12, 13, 14])
```

and the gain in clarity gets even greater when you start doing some non-trivial operations on more than two lists.

Back to my initial problem of selecting only some rows in a list of objects:

```
subset = [item[0] for item in zip(object,param1,param2,param3,param4) if item[1]>10 and item[2]-item[3]>5 and item[2]-item[3]<6 and item[4]==1]
```

or:

```
subset = [obj for obj,p1,p2,p3,p4 in zip(object,param1,param2,param3,param4) if p1>10 and p2-p3>5 and p2-p3<6 and p4==1]
```

perform exactly what I want, but I don't find that very elegant. Not to mention that non-pythoneers quickly start telling you "SuperMongo makes it easier" or "you want me to give up IDL for THIS!?".

Are you aware of alternative solutions offering a nicer syntax for this specific task? Can NumPy arrays, again, help simplifying the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy array version:

```
subset = objects[(param1>10) & (param2-param3>5) & (param2-param3<6) & (param4==1)]
```

but every operation in the [] will create a temporary array, if the size of your arrays are large, it may need some optimize.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for!
Bonus: Now I am think of a way to return the POSITION of the object and not the object itself. 

     index_of_subset = numpy.array(range(len(object)))[(param1>10) & (param2-param3>5) & (param2-param3<6) & (param4==1)]

works. There may be more intelligent ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your second example can be made quite readable if you indent properly:

```
[obj for obj, p1, p2, p3, p4 in zip(object, param1, param2, param3, param4) 
 if p1 > 10 
 and p2 - p3 > 5
 and p2 - p3 < 6
 and p4 == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I know I rarely indent (apart when articulating logical blocks) and that can improve the general aspect of my codes. The syntax is still the same though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) or just use a for loop.

Comment: `filter` won't clean anything up really, as the condition to filter on is independent of the value being filtered, so you'd still have to zip it all together.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`/`imap` combined with `compress`.

```
from itertools import imap, compress

compress(obj_list, imap(lambda p1, p2, p3, p4: p1 > 10 and 5 < p2 - p3 < 6 and p4 == 1, param1_list, param2_list, param3_list, param4_list))
```

You could also encapsulate it in to a function to provide a slightly cleaner interface.

```
mask_filter(filter_function, data, masks):

    return compress(data, imap(filter_function, masks))

mask_validator = lambda *params: params[0] > 10 and 5 < params[1] - params[2] < 6 and params[3] == 1
parameter_lists = (param1_list, param2_list, param3_list, param4_list)
mask_filter(mask_validator, obj_list, *parameter_lists)
```

Comment: This is beyond my current skills, and may not be the best solution for my specific need at the moment (I tend to uses the masks only once, which is why the shorter the syntax, to better). But since it is using some functions I don't know about I will try and see what I can learn from this, thanks.